# LSM Tree VS GRIDDB's In memory's approach differences

Tags: database, time-series, griddb

TimescaleDB uses a hyper-table to store data. Since GRIDDB also doesn't use LSM trees like TimescaleDB but other databases like InfluxDB do what is the fundamental difference behind Memory first, and Storage second with other approaches? Is it just stacking more in-memory storage or there is more to it?